# Can I handle-tie two 120V CH breakers for a 240V load?

Tags: electrical, 240v, 120-240v

Due to an ordering error a long time ago, I have too many 30A 1-pole "CH" brand breakers.  (these are single breakers, not tandem/double-stuff).  As you probably realize, there isn't much call for 120V/30A circuits, so these breakers are a dunsel.

However I have need for 30A 2-pole breakers for 240V and 120/240V circuits.

Can I use a handle-tie listed for these breakers to combine two 1-pole breakers into a 240V 2-pole breaker?  I am under NEC 2014.

Comment: Is this a 240V only load, or a 120/240V load?

Comment: Some of each.  It's CH type.

Comment: Is it too late to return them to the supplier and get the right parts?  Might cost you a restocking fee, but safety gear is not something to bodge.

Comment: @Criggie Far too late, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Eaton type CH is typical among modern breakers in that multipole common tripping is performed by an internal mechanism, not by the handle tie.  This is noted in the Eaton catalog in the spec description of the type CH breaker (page V1-T1-31 of the Eaton catalog, emphasis mine):

> **Product Description**
>
> Quick-make, quick-break switch mechanism combined with inverse time element tripping operation and trip-free handle design. Type CH circuit breakers trip to the OFF position, eliminating nuisance callbacks. The CHF family also includes a trip flag to differentiate between a trip and the breaker being turned off. The thermal-magnetic trip curve avoids nuisance tripping on mild overloads while reacting almost instantaneously to severe short-circuit conditions. *Multipole breakers have internal common trip connection to operate all poles simultaneously.* Handles are marked with ON-OFF indication and ampere rating of the breaker.

and in footnote 2 on the accessories table (page V1-T1-38):

> 2. Handle ties: typically used to join two similar independent single-pole breakers to form a two-pole noncommon trip breaker.

This means that the combination of 2 single pole type CH breakers and a handle tie is only usable for 240V only or 120V only circuits as per NEC 240.15(B)(1) and 240.15(B)(2):

> **(B) Circuit Breaker as Overcurrent Device.** Circuit
>   breakers shall open all ungrounded conductors of the circuit
>   both manually and automatically unless otherwise permitted in 240.15(B)(1), (B)(2), (B)(3), and (B)(4).
>
> **(1) Multiwire Branch Circuits.** Individual single-pole circuit breakers, with identified handle ties, shall be permitted
>   as the protection for each ungrounded conductor of multi-wire branch circuits that serve only single-phase line-to-neutral loads.
>
> **(2) Grounded Single-Phase Alternating-Current Circuits.** In grounded systems, individual single-pole circuit
>   breakers rated 120/240 volts ac, with identified handle ties,
>   shall be permitted as the protection for each ungrounded
>   conductor for line-to-line connected loads for single-phase
>   circuits.

As to breaker ratings, the CH line has you covered as well.  All standard (i.e. no GF or AF functions) single pole CH, CHF, CHT, CH-HID, CHP, CH-M50, CH-HM and CHP-HM breakers are rated 120/240VAC, so they are listed for handle tied service on 240VAC only split phase circuits.

Furthermore, the [UL Circuit Breaker Marking Guide](http://www.ul.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/CircuitBreaker_MG.pdf) states in paragraph 40 that

> An external handle tie alone does not
>   qualify as a common trip mechanism — a breaker of this type is marked to indicate it is an
>   independent trip breaker.

Answer (score 4):

It may not provide a legal breaker for a 30-A 240-V circuit such as for a dryer that uses 240 V and 120 V because the tie bar only works for manual shut-off. If one breaker trips due to over-current, it is not assured to pull off the other breaker unless that is an explicitly stated property of this model breaker.

I think the only use of tied 1-pole breakers is for powering circuits from two breakers with a shared neutral, an arrangement which I think is called a multi-wire branch circuit. But that would probably be with 20-A or 15-A breakers. I think you should return the extra 1-pole 30-A breakers.

Comment: You can also use two tied single pole breakers for a 240VAC only circuit such as a water heater.  You simply can't use them in mixed 120/240V applications.

Answer (score 2):

Adding listed handle ties to 2 120v breakers provides a legal 240 breaker. Added The 2014 NEC hand book 210.4.B commentary identifies that 2 single pole breakers with an identified handle tie or a 2 pole breaker is allowed. 210.4 is multiwire branch circuits. 230.71.B single pole switches or breakers shall be permitted on multiwire circuits, 1 pole for each ungrounded conductor.. with identified handle ties. 240.15.B.2 allows for line to line loads 120/240 breaker grounded system & identified handle ties.

Comment: A legal *independent trip* 2-pole breaker.  Some applications *require* a common trip function, which handle-tying doesn't provide.

Comment: I would agree but some cases allow for ties and they are legal. Unlike the 8 penny nail that used to be used.

Comment: The key is "listed", and although handle ties are available using them you must not only use a listed handle tie but two single pole breakers that are listed for use on 120/240 with a handle tie.  Most single pole won't carry the "/240" part.  It's easier to use a listed double pole breaker with an internal common trip than to try and prove you've met all the conditions. @ThreePhaseEel

Comment: @Tyson -- the listed handle tie actually isn't the hard part (any electrical supply house can get you them).  The problem is that handle tied single pole breakers still *trip* independently in all modern breaker designs (I suspect this is an inherent consequence of having the breaker "trip free").  This means that you can only use them where you only need both poles *disconnected* at once (i.e. 240VAC-only circuits and MWBCs), *not* in cases where both poles must *trip together* such as a ranger or dryer load with both 120VAC and 240VAC bits.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel right, the listed handle tie isn't the problem, finding a single pole breaker listed 120/240 is tho because single pole breakers don't carry the /240 part...  I hadn't adequately considered a MWBC tho...

Comment: @Tyson -- not sure what el cheapo breakers you're looking at, but my PDF copy of the Eaton catalog says that all of the regular single pole CHs are 120/240 rated

Comment: OP did not specify the country. You didn't, either. Thus, writing about "legal" is ambiguous at best.

Comment: @Mołot -- the type CH is a North American creature to begin with, and we're dealing with 120/240V split phase here, so this is North America man.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Sweet, and Americans knows that. But you are not the only nation on this site, please keep that in mind. Stack Exchange was supposed to be international, last time I checked.

Comment: @Molot, I do agree with ThreePhaseEel I gave reference to the NEC he provided model numbers we help where we can on all questions. Without some kind of standard used as a basis for our opinion the answers would be as useless as your comment about "legal". If your country has different standards please post those as answers trying to help folks and we may all learn something.

Answer (score -2):

No you can't use two single pole circuit breakers and tie the handles together per article 240.8

240.8 FUSES OR CIRCUIT BREAKERS IN PARALLEL
Fuses and circuit breakers shall be permitted to be connected in parallel where they are factory assembled in parallel and listed as a unit.  Individual fuses, circuit breakers, or combinations thereof shall NOT otherwise be connected in parallel

Comment: That code segment addresses *paralleling* so it applies to a slightly different question: "All I have is 14AWG wire, can I use two 15A breakers to feed a 30A load".

Answer (score -2):

What if you were using gfci breakers? Jumped the neutrals together that way when one trips they both trip and they are breaker tied together. Already tested it and it works fine. There for I took 2 single pole 120v. 20amp breakers and made them 20amp 240v. I have not found any issues with that.

Comment: Bad advice. Just because it works in your test doesn't mean it will work in a real-world fault situation, and it will not meet code requirements.

Answer (score -2):

Cutler Hammer breakers have a hole in he tip of the handles, and they also sell small plastic ties to connect their breakers together...I have done it many times.

Comment: -1 This doesn't add anything to the other answers that already explained when handle-tied breakers are legal (for MWBC or 240V-only circuits) and when they're illegal and dangerous (in ordinary 120/240 dryer/range circuits).