# Can I replace two Siemens QP type, handle tied, single pole 15 amp breakers with a tandem QT type in the same configuration?

Tags: circuit-breaker

Our Siemens electrical panel has two single pole 15 amp QP type breakers, with a handle tie that are together powering a mini-split HVAC system. One breaker has the white neutral line into it (wrapped in black tape as appears to be expected) and the other has black hot line.

Can I replace these with a tandem 15 amp QT type Siemens breaker (edit: specifically, model Q1515U)? Assuming I use a handle tie (model ECQTH2, which it looks like qualifies as a common trip for those breakers) and wire it with the same neutral line in one and hot line in the other.

Edit: fwiw, this panel does support tandems in every slot

Photo of the current breaker if it's helpful:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. Your current configuration puts each hot on a different leg, resulting in 240 volts (120+120). The tandem breaker you’re proposing puts both hots on the same 120 volt leg. This will result in zero volts across the hots. If this were a multi-wire branch circuit, you’d end up with double current on the neutral.

What you could use is a compatible quad breaker (4 breakers in the space for two) with appropriate handle ties to produce two 240 volt circuits or one 240 and two 120s.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to install two new 20A circuits for exterior outlets, and it doesn't look like Siemens makes a quad with 15A double pole inside and 20A single poles outside, so I'll have to find another way to do it.

Comment: Another breaker in the box is a 20A double pole powering a cadet heater, wired the same way as the 15A for the mini-split. So I will pick up a 20A quad with a double pole middle and two single pole outside breakers to swap in place of the current double pole 20A. That should do it!

Comment: @jbiscuit -- yep, a Q22020CT will do the job there.

Answer (score 1):

For a primer on how spaces in a panel work (vis-a-vis double-stuff breakers), [read my Q/A here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110151/what-is-a-tandem-breaker-aka-duplex-cheater-twin-double-stuff-etc).  Besides the fundamental problem that DoxyLover mentions, it is also impossible to fit handle-ties between the throws of a 1-pole duplex breaker. There would be no reason to do that since they are on the same pole.

Handle ties don't provide common trip.  Handle ties provide common maintenance shutoff *only*.  Handle-ties are mainly for MWBCs, which *do not* require common trip.  And are also permissible on 240V-*only* loads in most cases, e.g. A mini-split.

Some do make handle ties designed to go between two double-stuffs, so you would fit two 15A duplex breakers and form a 240V/15A common-maintenance-shutoff breaker in the middle positions.

Internal mechanisms within the breaker cause common trip, and two separate breakers just can't do that thing.  Since 120/240V (w/neutral) loads [generally require common trip](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/108180/47125), you must use a 2-pole or a quadplex.